# SAMPLE clause on GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle db where there are multiple rows with matching names. Now I need to sample on this db but don't want to alter the distribution by including rows with the same names multiple times.
What I tried is this.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT names, min(a), min(b) 
    FROM table GROUP BY names) SAMPLE(5);
```

That only gives

> ORA-00933 SQL command not properly ended

The inner SELECT by itself works just fine, just the outer SAMPLE clauce seems to be a problem. Is there a different way to put it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your tables so I'm using Scott's `emp`.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select job, min(sal), max(sal)
  3        from emp
  4        group by job
  5       )
  6  sample (8);
sample (8)
       *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

OK, so - let's use a CTE instead:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select job, min(sal) minsal, max(sal) maxsal
  3     from emp
  4     group by job
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from temp
  8  sample (8);
with temp as
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY,
etc.
```

Aha.

There's no *easy* way out (I mean, writing a standalone query). But, if you **materialize** the source (by creating a table based on a subquery), then it *works*:

```
SQL> create table test as
  2    select job, min(sal) minsal, max(sal) maxsal
  3    from emp
  4    group by job;

Table created.

SQL> select * from test;

JOB           MINSAL     MAXSAL
--------- ---------- ----------
CLERK            800       1300
SALESMAN        1250       1600
PRESIDENT       5000       5000
MANAGER         2450       2975
ANALYST         3000       3000

SQL> select *
  2  from test
  3  sample (8);

JOB           MINSAL     MAXSAL
--------- ---------- ----------
PRESIDENT       5000       5000
MANAGER         2450       2975

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6), `SAMPLE` is only valid for branch with physical object underneath (`[schema.]...`).

To achieve similar result with a subquery you may use:

- For all versions: calculate `row_number() over(order by null) as rn, count(*) over() as cnt` in the subquery and then filter by `rn <= ceil(cnt*N/100)`.
- For 12c and above: [`fetch first N percent rows only`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BABBADDD), which will do all the calculations under the hood. Note, that it does exactly the same as above for you without extra typing.

> ```
> create table t (names, a, b) as
> select
>   lpad(mod(level, 100), 3, '0')
>   , level
>   , level
> from dual
> connect by level < 300
> ```

> ```
> select /*+gather_plan_statistics*/ *
> from (
>   select names, min(a), min(b) 
>   from t
>   group by names
> )
> fetch first 8 percent rows only
> ```
>
> ```
> NAMES | MIN(A) | MIN(B)
> :---- | -----: | -----:
> 003   |      3 |      3
> 020   |     20 |     20
> 026   |     26 |     26
> 029   |     29 |     29
> 035   |     35 |     35
> 049   |     49 |     49
> 061   |     61 |     61
> 063   |     63 |     63
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=edbd726042c6fa951a43a6aacbce2acd)*

**But** keep in mind, that `SAMPLE` is physical operation, that's why it throws

> ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY,
> etc.

for view and it is the reason I wrote *similar*, not *the same*. In the plan:

```
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS SAMPLE| T    |
```